# Fix idle COMMIT and ROLLBACK queries spawned by mlflow when using postgres as backend store

Tags: postgresql, mlflow

I have deployed and mlflow tracking server that uses a postgres database as a backend store. I have noticed that mlflow would spawn COMMIT and ROLLBACK queries that never finish. Gradually over time these idle queries use up CPU resources.

How can I mitigate or resolve this issue?

Upgraded python from 3.9.18 to 3.11.8
Upgraded mlflow version from 2.9.2 to 2.10.2

expected bug to be fixed, no change

Answer (score 0):

If the `state` in `pg_stat_activity` is `idle`, the statements **are finished**. Such sessions don't consume resources.

If you get more and more connections, you either configured the connection pool too large, or this mlflow has a connection leak, which you should report as a bug to them.